# Marginalizing by sampling from the joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

For two random variables $x$ and $y$, if I can sample from the joint distribution $p(x, y)$, I can obtain samples from the marginal $p(x)$ by sampling from the joint distribution and ignoring the values of $y$. I want to make a formal argument for this. Something like:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p(x)} [f(x)]
&= \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)\,p(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)\,\int_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} p(x, y)\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \int_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}  f(x)\,p(x, y)\,dy\,dx \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{x, y \sim p(x, y)} [f(x)]
\end{align}
$$

Is this a reasonable argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. To add some detail: for the second equality, you've used that $\int_y p(x,y)\,dy = p(x)$ for all $x$. The third is justified since $f(x)$ is just a constant as far as $\int_y$ cares. And for the last line, to move to the joint integral you might invoke [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!